# The term ./gradlew was nnot recognised

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Error picture]

```
./gradlew: The term './gradlew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./gradlew clean./gradlew clean./gradlew clean./gradlew clean
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./gradlew:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\walee\Desktop\Coding\Flutter\Flutter Projects\learningdart> ./gradlew clean
./gradlew: The term './gradlew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check   
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./gradlew clean
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./gradlew:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: `./gradlew clean` must run in `android` folder. Try to `cd android` and run the command again.

Answer (score 0):

Like Rodrigo's comment, you should run `gradlew` inside the `android` folder, i.e. `C:\Users\walee\Desktop\Coding\Flutter\Flutter Projects\learningdart\android`. But this is only going to build the Android version and not the other possible devices like iOS, macOS, Windows, Linux...

Anyway, looks like you're trying to just build a Flutter project. The proper way to do it is to run `flutter build` in the root folder (the folder `learningdart` in your case). Now, if you'd like to actually run the app just use the command `flutter run`. Or if you actually need to clean stuff run both `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`. The former is going to clean not only the Android project but all other devices as well (It calls `gradle clean` behind the scenes for you) and the latter is going to download all dependencies.